# Passing data into UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am new to swift and have been experimenting with passing data between view controllers. I have been attempting to pass data from a view controller into a UITableViewCell, However once run my code has no effect.

**DetailViewController** 
(passes data to the libraryViewController)

```
 func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let DestViewController: LibraryMovieViewController = segue.destination as! LibraryMovieViewController

        DestViewController.movieTitle = movieTitle
        DestViewController.movieRelease = movieReleaseDate

    }
}
```

**UITableViewCell**

```
class MovieSearchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var posterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var overviewLabel: UILabel!

}
```

**LibraryViewController**

```
struct libMovie {
    //let mainImage: UIImage
    let title: String
    let release: String

}
class LibraryMovieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataSource: [libMovie] = []
    var movieTitle: String!
    var movieRelease: String!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadDataSource()
    }
    func loadDataSource(){
       // dataSource.append(libMovie(title: " \(movieTitle)", release: " \(movieRelease)"))
    }
}
extension LibraryMovieViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 115
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {

        guard let movieCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "libCell", for: indexPath) as? LibraryMovieTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let libMovie = dataSource[indexPath.row]

        movieCell.cellTitleLabel.text =  "Movie Title: \(movieTitle)"
        movieCell.cellReleaseLabel.text = "Release Date: \(movieRelease)"
        return movieCell
    }
}
```

I would expect that when the app is run that movieTitle and movieReleaseDate are passed from the detail view controller and input into the library table cell, this is initiated by tapping a button on the detail view controller.

However this seems to have no affect on the program or simply returns blank cells.
No errors are reported in console nor does the app crash

Answer (score 1):

In `prepareForSegue` you've passed data to `movieTitle` and `movieRelease`, while you're using `dataSource` to inflate data on tableView.

Either pass and object of [libMovie] to `DestViewController.dataSource` if you want to inflate multiple rows of different movies or return 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection` and pass set the label content in cell with movieTitle and movieRelease.

Comment: I receive an error "Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[libMovie]'" when trying to pass DestViewController.dataSource = movieTitle from the first view controller, I have also tried returning 1 from numberOfRowsInSection but this seems to have no affect.

Comment: Yes the compiler won't allow you to pass string to type [libMovie] for obvious reasons of type-safety in swift.
what you need to do is something of kind
`DestViewController.dataSource = [libMovie(title : "your title", release : "release content")]`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `dataSource.count`, but doesn't seem to pass that data to this view controller.

You can either hardcode the `numberOfRowsInSection` as 1 or pass the `dataSource` from the first view controller and update your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Returning 1 at numberOfRowsInSection seems to have no effect on the code. I'm not sure i follow your second suggestions do you mean pass dataSource from the first view controller as DestViewController.dataSource = movieTitle, because this produces an error "Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[libMovie]' "

Answer (score 0):

The data source in the destination view controller is empty, what do you expect?

Uncomment the line in `loadDataSource` and reload the table view.

```
func loadDataSource(){
    dataSource.append(ibMovie(title: movieTitle, release: movieRelease))
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And replace

```
movieCell.cellTitleLabel.text =  "Movie Title: \(movieTitle)"
movieCell.cellReleaseLabel.text = "Release Date: \(movieRelease)"
```

with

```
movieCell.cellTitleLabel.text =  "Movie Title: \(libMovie.title)"
movieCell.cellReleaseLabel.text = "Release Date: \(libMovie.release)"
```

Comment: I've edited the code like you have suggested but no data is passed to the title and detail text labels, they just display 'nil'